# Where did my SSD storage go?

Tags: mac, storage

iMac has 1 TB SSD. There are four Finder root-level folders: Applications (Size 45 GB), Library (Size 21 GB), System (Size 19 GB), Users (Size 183 GB), a total of 268 GB. On the desktop Macintosh HD says 1 TB, 261 GB free. Activity Monitor says Swap Used: 281 MB.

Where did the other approximately 1000 - 268 - 261 = 471 GB go? Just curious, thanks.

[image]

Comment: We’re going to need to see a screen shot of Disk Utility or the output of the command `diskutil list | grep "disk0\|disk1\|disk2\|disk3"`. You can post the output of the latter by piping the output to `pbcopy` (append `| pbcopy` to the command).  Then paste the result to the question with an [edit].

Comment: @Allan, `diskutil list | grep disk` gives the same output and is much simpler.

Comment: True @lhf. I put that there to exclude any potential external drives attached.  Now that I’m thinking about it, the command using regex  `diskutil list | grep "disk[0..3]”` would work equally as well.  I should have used that.

Comment: I'm going to link this to several duplicates where other people don't get how things add up. Please edit this to explain how the disk is partitioned - there's not nearly enough information to know what version of macOS you have, what storage settings are, if there are snapshots or purgeable space or other things that would make this all correct or all needing some fix.